# bmatrix lines too thick compared to another matrix

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, matrices, line

Here's a MWE showing a column matrix and a line matrix.  Both are nice to my eyes, except that the first one has thick vertical lines, while the second has small thin vertical lines:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tensor}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    \Psi &\equiv
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \phantom{\!\!{}_1} \tensor{\Psi}{_{1}} \\
        \phantom{\!\!{}_2} \tensor{\Psi}{_{2}} \\
        \phantom{\!\!{}_3} \tensor{\Psi}{_{3}} \\
        \phantom{\!\!{}_3} \tensor{\vdots}{_{\phantom{3}}} \\
        \phantom{\!\!{}_N} \tensor{\Psi}{_{N}}
    \end{bmatrix}\!,
    \\[1ex]
    \bar{\Psi} &\equiv \bigl[ \: \tensor{\bar{\Psi}}{_1}, \, \tensor{\bar{\Psi}}{_2}, \, \tensor{\bar{\Psi}}{_3}, \, \ldots, \, \tensor{\bar{\Psi}}{_N} \bigr].
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Here's a preview:

[image]

I tried other matrix environments for the second one (the horizontal matrix) but it was ugly, and didn't solved the line thickness.

So how can I make both matrices to have similar vertical line thickness?

Alternate MWE code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tensor}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    \Psi &\equiv
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \phantom{\!{}_1} \tensor{\Psi}{_{1}} \\[2pt]
        \phantom{\!{}_2} \tensor{\Psi}{_{2}} \\[2pt]
        \phantom{\!{}_3} \tensor{\Psi}{_{3}} \\
        \phantom{\!{}_3} \tensor{\vdots}{_{\phantom{3}}} \\
        \phantom{\!{}_N} \tensor{\Psi}{_{N}}
    \end{bmatrix}\!,
    \\[1ex]
    \bar{\Psi} &\equiv
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \, \tensor{\bar{\Psi}}{_1}, \, \tensor{\bar{\Psi}}{_2}, \, \tensor{\bar{\Psi}}{_3}, \, \ldots, \, \tensor{\bar{\Psi}}{_N}
    \end{bmatrix}\!.
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

The second bmatrix has thin vertical lines, while the first one has thick vertical lines.  How to make them the same?

Comment: Maybe useful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/453436/how-to-make-large-brace-and-parenthesis-thinner

Comment: You can use also this link: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/467940/brackets-with-the-same-linewidth